# Can an -ing or -ed clause be seen as a relative clause?

Tags: grammar

I'm confused with reducing clauses. I need help to understand reducing clauses in English. 
**For example:**

> The amount of goods transported by train totaled about 70 tonnes.

I think the full sentence may be 2 kinds below:

> The amount of goods that were transported by train totaled about 70 tonnes.

**or ( Ing or -ed clause**)

> The amount of goods were transported by train, and the amount of goods totaled about 70 tonnes.

Can anybody explain this kind of sentence clearly for me?

Comment: It's called "_Whiz_-Deletion". **If** you start with a noun phrase that consists of a noun followed by a relative clause, **and** if the relative clause has a relative pronoun (i.e, a _Wh_-word or _that_) as its subject, **and** if the verb phrase in the relative clause starts with an auxiliary _be_ (like the Passive and the Progressive constructions do), **then** the subject (_Wh-_) and the form of _be_ (_is_) may be deleted, but only together. What's why it's called _Wh-iz_-Deletion.

Comment: Your first sentence is an example of _Whiz_-Deletion's output, your second is an example of its input, and the third sentence is ungrammatical because only the _Wh-_ word -- and **not** the _-iz_ word -- has been deleted.

Comment: The third sentence is actually grammatical except for the mismatch in number (*amount ... were transported*) - which is even borderline acceptable because *goods* is plural. The real problem is that it has nothing to do with the first sentence.

Comment: The 3rd sentence (a) makes little sense (to me, at least) and (b) it does **not** mean what the 1st and 2nd sentences mean.  *The* **amount of** *goods were transported* is gobbledygook. And if you remove *amount of* then sentence #3 claims that **ALL** of *the goods* were sent by train. The other sentences say nothing about the proportion of *the goods* that were sent by train.

Answer (score -1):

In answer to your question, yes. When the relative clause contains a present or past participle and the auxiliary verb to be. In such cases both relative pronoun and auxiliary can be left out:
For example:
She was wearing a dress (which was) covered in blue flowers.
Most of the parents (who were) invited to the conference did not come.
Anyone (that is) caught writing on the walls will be expelled from school